# WPF UserControl Loaded after Window Loaded. How I can initialize UserControl variables?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

and thanks for your help.

I have developed this UserControl:

[image]

And what I want is to place many of them and connect them with lines when application starts, like this:

[image]

I need that the UserControl initialize some variables, so I put these variables in the Loaded event of the UserControl, like this:

```
    public Bubble()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BubbleInstance_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _canvas = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as Canvas;
        _connections = new ConnectionLines(_canvas);
    }
```

And, because I want those controls connected when application starts, I put this code in Window Loaded event:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bubble1.ConnectTo(bubble2);
        bubble1.ConnectTo(bubble3);
        bubble2.ConnectTo(bubble4);
    }
```

But here is the problem: When the application starts, those variables that I put in the UserControl Loaded event aren't initialized when ConnectedTo methods are called.

Here is my question: How can I initialize those UserControl variables before Window Loaded event ocurs?

Comment: Wouldn't moving `_connections = new ConnectionLines(_canvas);` to the `Bubble` constructor solve this?

Comment: @paul No, it doesn't. If I place that line in the constructor, the reference that _connections have to _canvas will be null.

Comment: Why does the ConnectTo rely on having the Visual tree available? Can you not simply remember the links between the bubbles, and when each bubble is loaded, then create the UI elements to represent the links?

Comment: @AlSki Well, the UI elements that represents the links are `Line` objects. The idea is that when the user drag a bubble, all the lines that touche the moving bubble have to be updated, so they continue touching the bubble. `Line` objects are drawn on `Canvas` when `Bubble.ConnectTo()` method are called. I want draw them in the moment that I call the `ConnectTo` method, so, I can't establish them before and later draw them.

Comment: @AlSki Anyway you gave me an idea. I can create `_connections` object in the constructor of `Bubble` and later when I call `ConnectTo` methods, I pass `_canvas` to the `_connections` object. I tried it and works, but anyway I think it's a patch. I would like to have an event where I can call `ConnectTo` method after `Bubble` was loaded.

Comment: Can you make ConnectTo conditional? If you have already got a canvas then call AddConnectionLine(), if you haven't then simply add the connection, and when you set the Canvas, then call AddConnectionLine() for each of the connections.